# Meaning of you in the sentence

Tags: pronouns, personal-pronouns

[image: Motivational poster]

> I believe in love and hope.
>   In jamming out by yourself in your room.
>   I believe in having someone tell you
>   You're beautiful.
>   I believe in miracles.
>   I believe in smiling until your cheeks hurt
>   and laughing until you cry.
>   But above all... I believe in God
>   and His unfailing Love.

What is the meaning of you here?
I guess you here refers to you all....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In very formal English, people use the word **one** to mean *people in general*.

> One should always be polite
>   ..meaning
>   *People in general* should always be polite

In informal English, people use the word **[you](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/you)** in the same way, meaning *people in general*. I think that is the intended meaning in this collection of maxims.

> I believe in smiling till **your** cheeks hurt
>   ...meaning
>   I believe that *people in general* should smile until their cheeks hurt.

Comment: Thanks @javalatte. I'm gonna turn that right tick green 